# How to append a vector as a row in a saved .RData file with R

Tags: r, rdata

The question a bit self explanatory but I should add that I do not want to load the file. I'm looking for something like `append = TRUE` for saving a `.RData` file . I want to do something like this:

`save(df, file="mtcars.Rda",append = TRUE)`

Here is a reproducible example:

```
# load data
  data("mtcars")
  head(mtcars)

# save original DF
  save(mtcars, file="mtcars.Rdata")

# create another DF
  df <- mtcars

# append DF to a saved Rdata file
  save(df, file="mtcars.Rdata",append = TRUE)
```

> Error in save(df, file = "mtcars.Rdata", append = TRUE) : 
>    object ‘TRUE’ not found

Comment: Does the `save()` function even have an `append` argument?

Comment: @ekstroem Apparently no, the save() function does note have an append argument. That's why I'm asking for another way around it. I'm trying to avoid `.csv` format for the sake of code efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, You'll have to `load` file to make changes in saved objects and then save those objects again. You can't even view names of objects stored without loading, let alone modifying contents.

If you want a one-line solution, you can write a function.

```
appendToFile <- function(newRow, savedFile){
    load(savedFile, new.env())
    df = rbind(df, newRow)
    save(df, file = savedFile)
}

df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 6:10)
save(df, file = "file.RData")
appendToFile(c(50, 100), "file.RData")

# Check if changes are saved
load("file.RData")
tail(df, 3)
##   x   y
##4  4   9
##5  5  10
##6 50 100
```

Comment: Hi @Narenda, thank you for your answer but I'm looking for a solution that does not load the file into memory.

Comment: @RafaelPereira With the default `save` as you show, the file will be compressed using the `gzip` algorithm. (See `?save` for details.) You will not be able to modify the compressed file in a meaningful way without at least decompressing it.  Even if `ascii=T` the data frame certainly isn't saved in row-order (R prefers things in column-order, generally), so "adding a row" is rather complex. I am 99% sure this answer is your only easy choice.

Comment: If you want to easily append rows, then CSV or TSV are your friends. If you want to read and write quickly and portably, you might want to check out [feather](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/03/29/feather/).

Answer (score 0):

SOmething like this may help for adding new objects to an existing .Rdata file:

```
add_object_to_rda <- function(obj, rda_file, overwrite = FALSE) {
    .dummy <- NULL
    if (!file.exists(rda_file)) save(.dummy, file = rda_file)

    old_e <- new.env()
    new_e <- new.env()

    load(file = rda_file, envir = old_e)

    name_obj <- deparse(substitute(obj))   # get the name of the object

    # new_e[[name_obj]] <- get(name_obj)     # use this only outside a function
    new_e[[name_obj]] <- obj

    # merge object from old environment with the new environment
    # ls(old_e) is a character vector of the object names
    if (overwrite) {
        # the old variables take precedence over the new ones
        invisible(sapply(ls(new_e), function(x)
            assign(x, get(x, envir = new_e), envir = old_e)))
        # And finally we save the variables in the environment
        save(list = ls(old_e), file = rda_file, envir = old_e)
    }
    else {
        invisible(sapply(ls(old_e), function(x)
            assign(x, get(x, envir = old_e), envir = new_e)))
        # And finally we save the variables in the environment
        save(list = ls(new_e), file = rda_file, envir = new_e)
    }
}
```