# Append new lines to a .Rda file in R

Tags: r, rda

Writing a fresh .Rda file to save a data.frame is easy:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4), b=c(5,6,7,8))
save(df,file="data.Rda")
```

But is it possible to write more data afterwards, there is no `append=TRUE` option using `save`.

Similarly, writing new lines to a text file is easy using:

```
write.table(df, file = 'data.txt', append=T)
```

However for large data.frames, the resulting file is much larger.

Comment: Adding append to save sounds interesting, but would it not be easier to use `load()` and than add something to it with `tibble::add_row()` or whatever other method?

Comment: You can't (in general)  append to Rdata file without loading it first, because of how the file format works. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741620/how-to-append-a-vector-as-a-row-in-a-saved-rdata-file-with-r

Answer (score 2):

If you use Microsoft R, you might want to check `RevoScaler` package, `rxImport` function in particular. It allows you to store compressed `data.frame` in file, it also allows you to append new lines to existing file without loading it into environment.

Hope this helps. Link on function documentation below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/r-reference/revoscaler/rximport