# Append list to existing file in R

Tags: r, list, append

In R, I have a list of 3 objects of different classes (namely "summary.glm", "numeric", and "list") and I would like to append it to an existing (currently empty) file, created as follows:

```
file.create("empty_file.RData")
```

I was trying to do this with

```
library(erer)
write.list(my_list, file="empty_file.RData", append=TRUE)
```

but it returns

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(z[[k]]) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"summary.glm"’ to a data.frame
```

Is there any other function that allows to append lists to an existing file that do not require the elements of such list to be data frames?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append a vector as a row in a saved .RData file with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741620/how-to-append-a-vector-as-a-row-in-a-saved-rdata-file-with-r)

Comment: You might look into connections. See `?file`. You should be able to open a file in append mode.